# How to fix the bug on Firefox c select?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, firefox

https://plnkr.co/edit/z2uW4O6D1uLFnsoLjWeb?p=preview

When mouse hovering over the block, the select must show. When you open the select and point at one of the options, the options should disappear immediately.

That works fine in chrome but not in Firefox. any idea how to fix this in FF?

```js
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('SpicyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.spice = 'very';

});
```

```css
.box {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">
  
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Controller example Plunker</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
      document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <div>Controller example</div>
    
    <div ng-controller="SpicyCtrl">
      <div class="box" ng-mouseover="active_dropdown = true"
         ng-mouseleave="active_dropdown = false">
        
        
        <div ng-show="active_dropdown">
        <select name="" id="">
          <option>lorem test test</option>
          <option>lorem test test</option>
          <option>lorem test test</option>
          <option>lorem test test</option>
          <option>lorem test test</option>
          <option>lorem test test</option>
        </select>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in Firefox, when you select dropdown it considers mouseleave for class="box" and sets,

> active_dropdown = false

What you can do is instead of ng-mouseleave="active_dropdown = false" you can give it a function ng-mouseleave="test($event)".

Now in you app.js add the function

```
$scope.test = function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName !== 'SELECT') { // Update the code accordingly
      $scope.active_dropdown = false;
    }
}
```